# How to fix navigation bar in wordpress?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, wordpress

I am working on a theme which has a dynamic menu when we scroll it goes hide. I want to fix it on the top just like w3school website. Any idea?
Is it a good option to use a plugin like [Sticky menu](https://wordpress.org/plugins/sticky-menu-or-anything-on-scroll/)

Here is the website link
https://spaceunlimited.in/

CSS

```
 .ehf-header #masthead {
    z-index: 30;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: can you post your code or share the site url?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Share Your site url. than i will try to help you.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_fixed_menu.asp

Comment: Sorry guys ! just updated the question

Comment: There are many option to fixed menubar on scroll. You can edit from dashboard settings and here are a link for your help. https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_sticky_header

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the following for `masthead` you can keep the brown borders on the side.

```
#masthead {
    z-index: 30;
    position: fixed;
    background: whitesmoke;
    top: 0;
    left: 20px;
    max-width: calc(100% - 40px);
}
```

Comment: Is masthead default css property or something?

Comment: no, it is the ID of the header

Answer (score 1):

Add this css

```
.ehf-header .headroom--unpinned{
    position:fixed !important;
    top:0px;
}
```